# Does Faust Streaming Consumer retry the offset commit if it fails?

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, faust

After investigating my consumer logs I found out the following error:

```
[ERROR] OffsetCommit failed for group gaming-processor on partition TopicPartition(topic='my_topic', partition=3) with offset OffsetAndMetadata(offset=29426192, metadata=''): UnknownTopicOrPartitionError
```

This error occurred when my kafka broker leader pod on GKE was rotating. I think this error is expected while rebalancing is occurring my question is if the application is going to retry to commit this offset again or will it only commit the next offset in the next commit wave? Additionally I would like to know if this can cause the consumer to re-read older messages that were already consumed or to lose any message that wasn't yet consumed.